# Accessing web3 prop from react-web3-provider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web3-react

I am having trouble following the basic functionality of react-web3-provider

I am surrounding the root of the component like this:

```js
import React, {
  Component
} from "react"

import {
  withWeb3
} from 'react-web3-provider';

import Web3 from 'web3';
import Web3Provider from 'react-web3-provider';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return ( <
      Web3Provider defaultProvider = {
        (cb) => cb(new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/YOUR_API_KEY")))
      }
      loading = "Loading..."
      error = {
        (err) => `Connection error: ${err.message}`
      } >
      <div className = "App" >
      <NavBar / >
        </div>
      </ Web3Provider >
    )
  }
}


export const NavBar = props => {
  const { web3 } = props
  return (
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          {" "}
          <Link> Partial f </Link>{" "}
        </li>
        <li>
          {" "}
          <Text.span> Wallet Address: {web3.eth.wallet[0]} </Text.span>{" "}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  )
}

export default withWeb3(NavBar)
```

```html
<script src="https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/develop/lib/web3.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/hussy-io/react-web3-provider/blob/master/src/index.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

However, I am not sure how I am supposed to get `web3` from props, as following their documentation, there are no props are passed down from the parent to the child component.

How can I get the instance of `web3`, just as in:

```
 class MyComponent {
    render() {
        const { web3 } = this.props;
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `withWeb3` HOC in documentation

```
import { withWeb3 } from 'react-web3-provider';

class MyComponent {
    render() {
        const { web3 } = this.props;

    }
}

export default withWeb3(MyComponent);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of this, but struggling to get it to work.

Comment: Do you mind demonstrating how it would be used with a function expression such as `NavBar` above please?